# Phrase search in recoll

Tags: search, recoll

I would like to know whether I could avoid [Recoll](http://recoll.org/) searching uses of any of the words in a term and only search the exact term.

For example I'm trying to search for *register indirect* and it gives searches of *register*,*indirect* and *register indirect* as shown below.I would only like to get searches of *register indirect*.

[image: Recoll]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclose the search terms in double quotes. e.g. "register indirect"

Comment: :Yeah it works.

Answer (score 3):

Or capitalize the terms if you want exact word matches but not necessarily consecutive and in order: [Register Indirect] will match [an indirect register] but not [register indirection]